# standardUserDefaults does not save boolean values

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

I have exhausted all my resources. The very simple process of storing a boolean value in `standardUserDefaults` simply does not work for me. Here's my test code:

```
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setBool:true forKey:@"BoolKey"];
            [defaults setObject:@"Hello!!!" forKey:@"StrKey"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            BOOL b = [defaults boolForKey:@"BoolKey"]; // b equals NO
            NSString *s = [defaults stringForKey:@"StrKey"]; // s equals "Hello!!!"
```

I can't understand why strings are stored fine, while booleans are not. Does anyone have any idea? I'm using XCode 6.0.1 (6A317).

---

Update: I found that changing the KeyName actually solved my problem. My boolean key was named `LoginOK`. I changed it to `CredentialsStored`, and now it loads correctly. Weird though...

Answer (score 3):

I copy pasted your code  and executed

Have look to bottom right in console 
BOOL returned YES

[image]

Comment: Well, it does not on my system. Should I uninstall and renistall XCode just for this?

Comment: Delete the app from iPhone / simulator and reinstall

Answer (score 1):

This issue has nothing to do with Xcode 6.0.1 (6A137). Your code is correct. I believe there could be an error at when you are calling or executing these commands. You should try and debug, start with a simple example and `NSlog` the values. Click on your `iOS Simulator` >> `Reset Contents and Settings` and try.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:true forKey:@"BoolKey"];
[defaults setObject:@"Hello!!!" forKey:@"StrKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

BOOL b = [defaults boolForKey:@"BoolKey"];
NSLog(@"%d",b);

NSString *s = [defaults stringForKey:@"StrKey"];
NSLog(@"%@",s);
```

Comment: I did, and the problem persists.